# Jquery save changes after editing the data

Tags: jquery

I have a function that adds a row:

```
        function addRow()
    {
        $('#sample_editable_1 tbody').append('<tr>'+
                                             '<td class="TDversion"> '+
                                             $('#version').val()+
                                             '</td>'+
                                             '<td>'+
                                             '<input type = "button" class = "editButton" value ="edit"></input>'+
                                             '<td>'+
                                             '<a class="cancel" href="">Delete</a>'+
                                             '</td>'+
                                             '</tr>');

        $('.editButton').on('click',function()
        {
            $("#myModal2").modal("show");
            $("#editVersion").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[0].textContent);

        });

        $('.saveChanges').on('click',function(){

        })
    }
```

I want to replace the data that was added in the row by the new data when pressing the saveChanges button after editing it

Comment: what do you mean by 'save'? you want the changes to stay even if the page is refreshed?

Comment: please create working js fiddle if possible

Comment: no I have a button "save changes" that has the class $('.saveChanges') I want the data to be saved (replaced) in the same row

Comment: the code is big i can't make a fiddle

Comment: At least provide related html so the fiddle can be created from that.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7seg7LLe/